# Get ground altitude in a reliable way

Tags: google-earth-plugin

How should a  program determine that the Google Earth API has fetched an accurate altitude for a location?

The Google Earth Plugin API has the following method to get ground altitude:

```
double GEGlobe.getGroundAltitude(double lat, double lon)
```

However, this function returns different results depending on the camera's distance from the targeted latitude, longitude. For example if the true altitude for a location is:  +181.60

Calling the function when the camera is at different distances from the location returns the following altitudes:

Return values of getGroundAltitude at different camera positions:

-19.38   (camera is very far from location)

+06.11   (camera is now closer)

+89.13   (...)

+166.82

+177.47

+181.53  (camera is now v.close to the location)

The returned value 181.53 is close enough to true altitude of 181.60

The question is, how should the program determine that it has reliably got the most accurate altitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls of Google Earth. The ground altitude thing depends on the quality of imagery that is available for that given point. So, it the imagery is good, the value will be accurate, if the imagery is bad the value could be bad.

You can check how much imagery is loaded with `getStreamingPercent()` -- the ground altitude value should get more accurate as the streaming percent increases.

You may want to use Google's elevation API, which actually calls out to get the data from an external server (where the % loaded doesn't come into play.) The downside to this method is that it requires internet connectivity, so that's something to keep in mind.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

**Edit**

Another thing to remember, that `getGroundAltitude()` call is very finicky. It's trying to get the value for a single point on the Earth -- but it doesn't have very good error checking (ie. it might not know the value for point X,Y, so it returns something wrong even though all points surrounding X,Y have valid data.)

Comment: That answered my doubts. Thank you!

Comment: "but it doesn't have very good error checking" - I see what you mean. The docs say `getGroundAltitude` returns zero if altitude data for the location has not yet been loaded.  If it worked this way (better still, if it returned NaN) it could have been useful to me. `getGroundAltitude` seems like complimentary data to the main part which is imagery.  As you said, I've been looking at Google's elevation API. I've also taken a look at [Map Quest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/) which provides a web endpoint to read elevation and other such earth data.

Comment: Incase its useful to others: MapQuest has a web service, supports JSONP which is useful for browser based javascript (ie. MapQuest can return data wrapped inside a callback function).  Google Elevation service doesn't seem to support JSONP callback. MapQuest elevations differ from Google Elevation Service at times by upto +11/-11 meters. Sometimes more, sometimes less, sometimes almost equal. This doesn't necessarily speak about which is more accurate; that would be better answered by an expert. After all my guess is that both would have interpolated data to some extent.

Comment: Would be useful if anyone has insights in using other elevation services.