# Highest Altitude with best terrain data

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a program that uses the API to get altitude data of the screen by running through hundreds of thousands of latitude and longitude points.  However, Google Earth's data refines itself as one zooms in.  So I need to know the minimum altitude I can use to get the best data Google has to offer.  I am at a loss to figure out how to do this.

Furthermore, I assume that this depends on the part of the world.  I'm going to assume the best part of the world, always.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ground altitude in a reliable way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458498/get-ground-altitude-in-a-reliable-way)

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for determining the quality of the underlying imagery. While this question is not an exact duplicate of [Get ground altitude in a reliable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458498/get-ground-altitude-in-a-reliable-way), the same general algorithm can be applied:

1. Zoom to the required lat/lon at altitude Z
2. Wait for the imagery to come in (as described in the linked question)
3. Zoom in "closer" (Z - [delta])
4. If Google has better imagery, the loaded percentage should drop, wait for it load
5. Repeat steps 3-4 until the progress is always ~100% (e.g., until no loading is required)

Even with this hack, I'm not sure it will yield reliable results. Your question is flawed for several reasons:

1. What does "the best data Google has to offer" mean?

   - You have a lat/lon coordinate. That's a single, infinitely small, point on the Earth
   - Raw satellite imagery typically covers large sections (many lat/lon points), so the "best" height would be to set the GE camera so that your view convers exactly one satellite image tile
2. Why do you need the "best" data?

   - Satellite imagery is expressed in terms of "area covered by a single pixel" (e.g., 1m = 1 pixel in the image covers 1sq m)
   - Knowing this, the camera height will vary image by image, even for tiles within the same satellite imagery data set (it shouldn't vary much -- but it could slightly.)

Are you trying to cache the imagery off the globe? If so, you should carefully review the TOS to make sure you're not in violation.

Note that if you are just looking to obtain satellite imagery -- there are many good (free) sources. [USGS National Map Viewer](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/) should be able to get you pretty good imagery for the US (including territories).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
1. If I am too high, the latitude and longitude points do not yield the same as if I zoom in.  Therefore the best data Google Earth has to offer is presented only when the user is at the correct height above the Earth. This height is not a constant, it is different at different parts of the world, as you say in part 2.  Your answer is obvious, my question is how to know that my view covers one satellite image tile.  I need the best data because my program depends on altitude data, it is less accurate with worse data.